# Como eu informo um condição para quando a tela for alterada o timer.periodic cancelar

Tags: flutter, dart, async

Hoje utilizo assim com o código a baixo, mas não funciona muito bem, pois ao alterar de tela a consulta continua a ser executada em background.

```
Future _refresh() async {
  if (_statusLote != "finalizado") {
    _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 30), (timer) {
      print("Com atualizações");
      print(_statusLote);
      setState(() {
        pegarCarcacas();
      });
    });
  } else {
    print("Sem atualizações");
    print(_statusLote);
    closeTimer();
  }
}
```

Comment: Como é um usuário novo vai uma dica pra gente te ajudar melhor. Edite sua pergunta montando o cenário completo do seu problema explicando claramente o seu código se propõe a resolver. Depois insira códigos funcionais para que os membros da comunidade consigam entender e te ajudar melhor. Cite também o que já fez de tentativas de solução caso tenha tentado algo. Não tenha medo de detalhar, desde que as informações ajudem no entendimento, detalhes são muito bem vindos.

Comment: Se for o que entendi, seu problema é que ao sair da tela onde tem esse trecho de código o app deveria parar de fazer consultas. É isso mesmo? Se for dentro desse Timer que as consultas ocorram, não teria algum processo no seu código que possa utilizar para pausar ele ao ser direcionado para a tela seguinte? Enfim, com os detalhes será mais fácil te ajudar.

Comment: Então para as minhas necessidades necessito que um nova consulta e o retorno da mesma juntamente com a atualização tela sejam atualizadas a cada 30s, até ok. Problema e quando o usuário sai dessa tela, a consulta continua a ser realizada. O retorno da consulta traz uma informação de status que é alterada no meu backend, porem essa alteração pode levar até horas, não seria adequado esperar somente esse evento ocorrer para as consultas sessarem. Quero realmente resolver esse erro inesperado da consulta que fica rodando mesmo não estando na tela onde foi startada.

Comment: Resolvido: Retirei minha função _refresh() do Build e a adicionei no initstate(). Além disso envolvi a build em um WillPopScope, com isso consigo travar o botão de voltar e executar o cancelamento do periodic time. Obrigado a todos pela atenção.

Comment: Que bom que solucionou o seu problema. Agora que já tem a sua solução, recomendo que poste ela em formato de resposta assim poderá ser melhor utilizada futuramente. Um outro ponto que recomendo é sobre os códigos "picados", pois pelo que notei, sua pergunta não deixou claro como estava a estrutura da sua classe e isso afeta diretamente nas sugestões de correção. Caso decida postar a solução coloque sua classe completa na resposta.

Comment: @WeberthMoreira responda sua pergunta com a forma que você resolveu ai, isso pode ajudar quem tiver o mesmo problema futuramente...

Answer (score 0):

Tente mudar sua variável `Timer` local para uma variável global dentro da sua classe e trate ela no `dispose` da sua classe, segue abaixo um exemplo:

```
class YellowBird extends StatefulWidget {
  const YellowBird({ Key key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _YellowBirdState createState() => _YellowBirdState();
}

class _YellowBirdState extends State<YellowBird> {

  Timer _timer;

  @override
  dispose(){
    closeTimer();
    super.dispose;
  }

  void closeTimer(){
    if (_timer.isActive)
      _timer.cancel();
  }


  Future _refresh() async {
    if (_statusLote != "finalizado") {
      _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 30), (timer) {
          print("Com atualizações");
          print(_statusLote);
          setState(() {
            pegarCarcacas();
          });
        });
    } else {
      print("Sem atualizações");
      print(_statusLote);
      closeTimer();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(color: const Color(0xFFFFE306));
  }
}
```

Comment: Mesma situação e apresenta após sugestão do @Matheus Ribeiro.

Comment: @WeberthMoreira aconselho que nas próximas perguntas, você informe o máximo possível de dados, se houvesse dito que sua função era chamada dentro do `build()` poderíamos ter te ajudado em questão de minutos!